# How can we handle disabling of dropdown selection in react hooks web app without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multiselect-react-dropdown

How can we handle disabling of dropdown selection in react hooks web app without refreshing the page ? In my case, I have a multiselect dropdown box. When I selected an item from the dropdown, display a text field, once after typing some text and submit it, details get saved into database. Once saved into DB, the respective dropdown item should be disabled for selection.

[image]

But in my case, its not immediately disabled after submit. Its is disabled only after i manually refresh the page. How can I fix this issue, can someone please advise ?

```
  const [option, setOption] = useState([]);
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState([]);
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    watch,
    formState: { errors },
    reset,
  } = useForm();

  const refSelect = useRef(null);
  const [submittedNominees, setSubmittedNominees] = useState([{}]);
  const [maxOptions, setMaxOptions] = useState(0); 
  const [showOptions, setShowOptions] = useState(false); 


    const focusOnInput = () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          document.querySelector("input").focus();
        // Adding some delay to allow the component to re-mount
        }, 10);
      };
    
      const handleTypeSelect = (e, i) => {
        const copy = [...selectedOption];
        copy.push(e[3 - maxOptions]); //A.H-fix error: select one more record it still console log the pre selected one
        setSelectedOption(copy);
        setMaxOptions((prevState) => prevState - 1); //A.H-making maxOption dynamic
        focusOnInput();
      };
    
      const handleTypeRemove = (e) => {
        const copy = [...selectedOption];
        let index = copy.indexOf(e);
        copy.splice(index, 1);
        setSelectedOption(copy);
        setMaxOptions((prevState) => prevState + 1);         
        // immutating state (best practice)
        const updateList = nomRegister.map((item) => {
          return { ...item };
        });
        //delete the specific array case depends on the id
        updateList.splice(index, 1);
        setNomRegister(updateList);
        focusOnInput();
      };
    
    
        useEffect(() => {
            const fetchData = async () => {
              const userEmail = localStorage.getItem("loginEmail");
              try {
                let res = [];
                res = await Axios.get(
                  `${appURL}/service/submittednominations`,
                    {params:{userEmail}}
                );
                const data1 = res.data;
                console.log(data1, "data1");
                  setSubmittedNominees(data1);
                  setMaxOptions(3 - data1.length); //maxOption dynamic because we don't the length of data from submittednominations
                  console.log("Submitted nominations :" + JSON.stringify(data1));
              } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
              }
            };
            fetchData();
          }, []);
```

Droddown box:

```
<section className="col1">
        <div className='nomineeSelectBox'>
          <div id='dialog2' className='triangle_down1' />
          <div className='arrowdown'>
            <Multiselect
              ref={refSelect}
              onSelect={(e) => handleTypeSelect(e, selectedOption.length)}
              onRemove={handleTypeRemove}
              options={!showOptions ? [] : option}
              displayValue='displayValue'
              disablePreSelectedValues={true}
              selectedValues={submittedNominees}
              showCheckbox={true}
              emptyRecordMsg={"Maximum nominees selected !"}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what or where the select is being disabled? I'm looking for a `disabled` prop, but perhaps I don't understand the code or you've not included all the relevant code as part of your [mcve]?

Comment: Sure, ``disablePreSelectedValues={true}`` and this will be based on the `` selectedValues={submittedNominees}``` received from the database via service call ```..../service/submittednominations``

Comment: Using a  list of dependency in that page, while trying to create a reproducile page, some of the are not loading ...
``
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import Axios from "axios";
import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import Multiselect from "multiselect-react-dropdown";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
``

Comment: List continues ...
``import Dialog from "@material-ui/core/Dialog";
import DialogActions from "@material-ui/core/DialogActions";
import DialogContent from "@material-ui/core/DialogContent";
import DialogContentText from "@material-ui/core/DialogContentText";
import DialogTitle from "@material-ui/core/DialogTitle";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import { notify } from "./helperFunctions";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css"``

Comment: Once submit, the selected item is enabled in the dropdown list box, but after refreshing the page, the selected item gets disabled in the dropdown list. I have called the ``service/submittednominations```in useEffect...but still it needs the page to refreshed..

Comment: I have tried to create a minimal reproducible example CSB link, but some of the dependencies are not loading

Answer (score 0):

If you add the changed state to the dependency list of the `useEffect()`, it will re-run that section of code inside.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // this code will re-run every time "selectedOptions" is changed
  // therefore every time "handleTypeSelect()" or "handleRemove()" is run
  const fetchData = async () => {
    ...
}, [selectedOption])
```

This will trigger a fresh list of `submittedNominees`, and cause a rerender (just the component, not the whole page) because `submittedNominees` is one of the render properties

```
<Multiselect
  ...
  selectedValues={submittedNominees}
  ...
  />
```

Alternatively (and probably quicker UI), make a call to `setSubmittedNominees()` inside `handleTypeSelect()` and `handleRemove()`. That will also trigger a component rerender.